# Can I use docker to provide a simple file overlay over my current system?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, docker, containers, sandbox

I am using **ubuntu** and I want to build and run a bunch of complex system components that would replace the existing ones (in my case, `packagekit` and `gstreamer`).

I don't want to take the risk to damage my system and I'm looking for ways to have an overlay (or sandbox) over my complete file system but still being able to use all the current tools and packages that are installed.

**Can docker help me?**

> Note: I said that those components were *complex* because they use the apt package system or gtk components. They are not isolated libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Just install your components each on a docker container.

There are even entire OS's that operate that way: e.g. [RancherOS](http://rancher.com/rancher-os/) or [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/)

In RancherOS, *everything* is inside a docker container (except the first daemon). The Docker daemon runs as `PID 1`.

Comment: I thought about it it. But the list is huge: apt, gtk, gstreamer, vala... I have the impression that this is overkill for my needs.

Comment: You *could* try running all your changes inside a single container that you build using a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, spin up as many containers with your own OS inside as docker containers. And you can use them as individual systems. But this helps only if you are not dealing with any persistent data